# How do I construct this class in DART so that I use a required parameter to save/query?

Tags: firebase, flutter, class, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class called `MessageDao` that I'm going to use as the class that will handle all read/write/update operations with Firebase Realtime Database.

The desired outcome is that if I use this class anywhere in my app, I should be passing a `groupIDPath` string to it that will be used to locate the appropriate node in Realtime Database. From there, I should be able to read/write/update as needed.

I tried doing this below, but I get an error pointing to `groupIDPath` in the line where I've left a comment. The error says : `The instance member 'groupIDPath' can't be accessed in an initializer.`  I read the documentation but I didn't quite understand their example of the alternatives. Given what I am trying to accomplish here, how should I structure this class?

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'message.dart';

class MessageDao {

  MessageDao({required this.groupIDPath});

  String groupIDPath; //example = 'groupChats/0exUS3P2XKFQ007TIMmm'
  DatabaseReference _messagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(groupIDPath); //ERROR IS HERE

  //Get stream of messages from realtime database based on group ID

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `_messagesRef` in the [initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list):

```dart
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'message.dart';

class MessageDao {

  MessageDao({required this.groupIDPath}):
      _messagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(groupIDPath);

  String groupIDPath;
  DatabaseReference _messagesRef;
}
```